# JavaFX changing a labels size

Tags: javafx, label

So I'm making a program and I need a label to be larger that the text is without the text getting bigger. How do I set the height and width of the label properly?

Comment: show what you tired. and what error you are getting?

Comment: Its not that I'm getting any errors. I've looked through all the methods in the label and none of them seem to allow me to set the height and width of my label.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without more details of what you are doing and what, exactly, you are trying to do. But methods like [`setPrefWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPrefWidth-double-), [`setPrefHeight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPrefHeight-double-), [`setPadding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPadding-javafx.geometry.Insets-) will change the size, as will using constraints specific to the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will change the size of the label without changing the size of the text:

```
Label label = new Label("This is a label");
label.setMinWidth(50);
label.setMinHeight(50);
```

To change the text/font you could use Font class or font method.

Answer (score 2):

You can update a label's max width using the css property:

```
-fx-max-width:50
```